# in which event can i handle the hyper link in the grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink, templatefield

I have a `gridview` which contains a hyper link as a template field ,now i wanna to use row command to handle the click on this hyperlink but,no command name or command argument for the hyper link .How to do this?

---

```
<asp:TemplateField>

<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" Target="_blank" Font-Names="Tahoma"
 Font-Size="Small">[HyperLink3]</asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
```

Note : i need to use Hyper link, not linkbutton .

Comment: Did you look at http://ranafaisal.wordpress.com/2008/03/31/how-to-get-the-current-row-in-gridview-row-command-event/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView's RowDataBound Event .

you can find the link control and add an arribute to it.

```
HyperLink lnkObj = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("HyperLink3");
lnkObj.Attributes.Add("onclick", <write your code> );
```